# ffmpeg and jwplayer video not working

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jwplayer

The converted .mp4 file through ffmpeg is working fine in my local machine. The command which i used is

```
exec('ffmpeg -i inputfile.flv -vcodec libx264 outputfile.mp4');
```

But it is not working in the server. The converted file size shows 0 bites. I think codec libx256 is not supported in centos.

Comment: Can you provide some additional information?  What is the output from ffmpeg?  Does it look like it is actually doing anything on the server?  Make sure libx264 is installed on the server and that FFMpeg is compiled with x264 support.  You should be getting a codec missing error if it is not compiled with 264 support